# How to filter list emitted by observable using result from another observable rx kotlin?

Tags: rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

Let say that I have a source of number list and observable which can value each number in that list. (Below method are required to be used. They are part of API which I **have to** use)

```
fun getNumberListSource() : Observable<List<Int>> {...}
fun getOddChecker(value: Int): Observable<Boolean> {...}
```

Let say source could look like this:

```
class NumberSource {

    private val source = BehaviorSubject.create<List<Int>>()

    fun getNumberListSource(): Observable<List<Int>> = source.doOnNext { println("doOnNext :)") }

    fun start(){
        Thread {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            source.onNext(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            source.onNext(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
            Thread.sleep(1000)

            source.onComplete()
        }.start()

    }
}
```

fun getOddChecker(i: Int) : Observable = Observable.just(i%2== 0)

at the end of the stream I need to have lists of odd numbers.
So I done that code:

```
fun main() {
    val numberSource = NumberSource()
    numberSource.start()
    println("== started ==")

    numberSource.getNumberListSource()
        .flatMap {
            Observable.fromIterable(it)
                .flatMap (
                    {getOddChecker(it)},
                    {a, b -> a to b}
                )
                .filter { it.second }
                .map { it.first }
                .toList()
                .toObservable()
        }
        .subscribe({ println("onNext: $it")},{},{ print("action:onComplete")})

}
```

above code's output:

```
== started == 
doOnNext :) 
onNext: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12] 
doOnNext :) 
onNext: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12] 
action:onComplete
```

Above code does what I want but I had to use `Pair` class. The part

```
        .filter { it.second }
        .map { it.first }
```

seems not quite readable.
So is there any operator witch could simplify that code?

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce it to something like this

```
   getNumberListSource()
           .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it)
                    .flatMap { item -> getOddChecker(item).filter {it}.map { item } }
                    .toList().toObservable()
            }
            .subscribe({ println("onNext: $it")},{},{ print("action:onComplete")})
```

Comment: getOddChecker is needed. It's part of domain api.

Comment: what exactly getOddChecker does?

Comment: it maks http request. This example is simplification of my real problem: I get list of products and special endpoint which makes classification base on product id. If endpoind returns false the app should not display product (remove from list).

Comment: Understood. I have updated the answer as per your requirement

Comment: almost. Now if observable emit more then one list then result will be concat. Also it waits till observable complete.

Comment: your code generates: onNext: [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

Comment: Okay. Got it. So you need the result as a stream instead of concatenating. Updated answer again.